# Laravel - using Google 2FA to protect all views

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm working on my first Laravel project and have implemented 2FA according to [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-add-googles-two-factor-authentication-to-laravel) but unfortunately, the 2FA mechanism created is attached only to `HomeController`.

So if a user tries to access `www.thingy.com/something` from an unauthenticated state, they enter email and password as usual and then get directly to `/something` without the 2FA prompt appearing.

My first thought was adding the middleware bit to every `__construct()` function in each of my resource controllers, but they don't already have a `__construct()` function (can I add one anyway?) and even if that worked, it doesn't seem like the right way of doing it.

I also considered adding it to `Controller` itself since that's what every other controller is based on, but of course I wouldn't want 2FA required for non-authenticated views too (just register, login etc really because the site requires a login to use).

What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Please show your code that implements this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [add the middleware to a group of routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-group-middleware) in your `routes/web.php` file.

```
Route::middleware('2fa')->group(function () {

    // All routes here will go through the "2fa" middleware

});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!